# How to implement monaco-editor on a webpage without nodejs and electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, monaco-editor

i am trying to make a simple web editor i found this thing called Monaco-editor and I've seen someone use it with electron but I want to just use it in plain javascript like on their webpage ([link](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/)) but how do I do this? I was searching google but I can't find any info on how to implement it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I built a simple project for creating a Knockout binding handler for the Monaco editor and it creates editor instances in browser purely client side. It simply loads the required Monaco resources from the Monaco GitHub repo. So the project index.html contains all the link and script tags required and the most important require configuration that points root to the repo script block is also present. Monaco uses a custom AMD based loader and so upon loading the loader.js script the custom loader is stored in the global require variable.

https://github.com/simpert/MonacoEditorKnockoutBindingHandler

Hope this helps.